# JFrame background color will not change

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jframe

I have viewed many answers here and changed my code accordingly but it still does not work correctly. Can someone help me fix it please?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LoginGUI extends JFrame {



    LoginGUI() { 

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JLabel title = new JLabel("HTML Generator");
        title.setForeground(Color.black);
        p.add(title);
        c.add(p);
        title.setOpaque(true);

        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new LoginGUI();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JPanel`'s opaque property is true by default, and `JFrame` default layout is `BorderLayout`. Adding only one component (the `JPanel`) to the frame, will stretch it the full size of the frame, as that's what `BorderLayout` will do. So, an  opaque panel covering the entire frame, that explains the results you are getting.

Three simple fixes.  Either set the `JPanel` opaque property to false, or just set the background on the `JPanel`, or set the layout of the frame to `GridBagLayout` or `FlowLayout`

Comment: Setting p.setOpaque(false); fixed my problem, than you very much.